# Using logical operators stored in character variables while subsetting data frame in R

Tags: r, logical-operators

My R script get three inputs from user which are read into var1, var2 and var3.

I am trying to perform a simple subset operation for data frame. The pseudocode of my thinking is 
shown below:

```
subset_data_frame<- dat[ dat[[var1]] var2 var3 , ]

where     var1= column name from dat
          var2= can be any of the logical operator like '==', '>', '<' etc.
          var3= numeric value
```

But this doesn't work because of the way I used the logical operator from var2.

Please suggest me an alternate way to get out of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is entering these variables as characters, then you'll need to create and evaluate a call.  Here's an example using the `mtcars` data set:

```
var1 <- "mpg"
var2 <- ">"
var3 <- "30"

expr <- call(var2, mtcars[[var1]], as.numeric(var3))

## or you could also construct a function call with substitute()
# expr <- substitute(
#     FUN(mtcars[[column]], value), 
#     list(FUN = as.name(var2), column = var1, value = as.numeric(var3))
# )
```

Now we have created an unevaluated call `expr` which can then be evaluated with `eval`

```
mtcars[eval(expr),]
#                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Fiat 128       32.4   4 78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# Honda Civic    30.4   4 75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
# Toyota Corolla 33.9   4 71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
# Lotus Europa   30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) Regular Expression

You first need to construct a legit expression based on user's input and then evaluate that string as a command. Here is a POC.

```
> cmd <- "iris[iris$1% 2% 3%,]"
> columnname <- readline("columnname:")
columnname:Sepal.Length
> operator <- readline("operator:")
operator:<
> value <- readline("value:")
value:5
> cmd <- gsub("1%", columnname, cmd)
> cmd <- gsub("2%", operator, cmd)
> cmd <- gsub("3%", value, cmd)
> cmd
[1] "iris[iris$Sepal.Length < 5,]"
> eval(parse(text=cmd))
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa
10           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
12           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2     setosa
13           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1     setosa
...
```

(2) Metaprogram

[Here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html) is a chapter - Expressions from HadleyWickham's advanced R. In there, he explains the ins-and-outs of how to program "program".

Answer (score 0):

**Step1.** make a character vector of the desired expression:

```
expr<-paste(dat[[var1]],var2,var3,sep = " ")
```

**Step2.** evaluate the expression to make a logical vector

```
myLogicalVec<-sapply(expr, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
```

**Step3.** use that logical vector in your data frame

```
dat[myLogicalVec,]
```

I am fairly new to R and there can be optimal ways of doing it. This is somewhat similar to Richard Scriven's answer but my thought process went like this.

Comment: Anurag Priyadarshi, Your code is short and simple.. Thanks.. I will let you know if I see any performance issues with bigger data sets.